# WCF Exception : There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter

Tags: asp.net, wcf

My `WCF` service is developed in .Net 3.0 and developed application which is consuming WCF in 3.5. When I try to consume my WCF then I am getting below error --

> "The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the
>   message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter
>   criteria. The InnerException message was 'Invalid enum value
>   'Positions' cannot be deserialized into type 'SecurityContents'.
>   Ensure that the necessary enum values are present and are marked with
>   EnumMemberAttribute attribute if the type has DataContractAttribute
>   attribute.'.  Please see InnerException for more details."

Please help me out in this.

Answer (score 1):

This error means there is a new SecurityContents enum value of "Positions" that your client doesn't know about.  You likely need to update your service reference.

[image]

I've also seen this if you `Reuse types in referenced assemblies`.  Try unchecking this.

[image]

Comment: I have not used it via update service reference. I have used channel factory. Any Idea what can be an issue?

Comment: Its been a long while since I used channel factory but I believe its the same problem.  The version of SecurityContents enum you have doesn't match what the service has. you need to compare them and make sure they are the same.